# window resize only works once

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got a function within a window.resize event and it works well, apart from that it seems to only works once. If the user resizes the window again the function isn't executed. This is the code:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
   var wait = setInterval(function () {
       if (!$(currentBanner, loading).is(":animated")) {
           clearInterval(wait);
           loading.stop().fadeOut(300, function () {
               if ($('#banner').css('display') == 'block'){
                   setTimeout(function() {
                       bannerInit();
                   }, 800);
                   startInterval();
                   if (initialLoad) {
                       initialLoad = false;
                       next.slideDown();
                       previous.slideDown();
                   }
               }
           });
       }
   }, 200);
}).resize();
```

Anybody know how I can make sure that the function is executed every time the window is resized?

Comment: This works only when the currentbanner, loading is animated. So if that animates only once, then this works only once.

Comment: @PraveenKumar There is a negation sign, so it should work when it is not animated.

Comment: @TaReQMahMooD I mean... Okay, right. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what was your intention but if it was to have a delayed execution after the window resize you should change setInterval to setTimeout

setInterval is a infinite loop that runs until you tell it to stop and setTimeout is only executed once and it will wait x milliseconds to be executed.

Plus, you dont need to call 'resize()' event, it will be fired everytime the window size is changed by any reason (user resizing or maximizing, etc)

```
$(window).on("resize",function() {
   var wait = setTimeout(function () {
       if (!$(currentBanner, loading).is(":animated")) {
           clearInterval(wait);
           loading.stop().fadeOut(300, function () {
               if ($('#banner').css('display') == 'block'){
                   setTimeout(function() {
                       bannerInit();
                   }, 800);
                   startInterval();
                   if (initialLoad) {
                       initialLoad = false;
                       next.slideDown();
                       previous.slideDown();
                   }
               }
           });
       }
   }, 200);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

That's because you're calling `.resize()` at the end of the event definition.

Try changing to:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
//....
});

$(window).resize();
```

Comment: resize(..) returns Window object so that shouldn't be a problem

Comment: @jgasiorowski I tested it and when there's a .resize at the end, it doesn't call the event besides the first time.

Comment: I tested that code and it works perfectly $(window).resize(function() { alert('Alert! Resize!'); }).resize(); (btw I didn't downgraded your answer ;) )

Comment: @jgasiorowski hm, when i ran that in the chrome dev tools it didn't work, i'll try more later. I''m not worried about the downgrade :)